# Angular JS - ui.router navigation is looping when clicking on nav items continuously

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

We are using ui.router for routing in a project.

We are facing a weird issue when we click on nav items continously, 
all the nav pages are going in looping and never stops the loop and its getting crashed.

Anybody has faced this kind of issue or what is so wrong we are doing here?

Comment: Could you mimic the issue in a plunkr possibly?

Comment: it is probably related with your otherwise defination... If you put some more code maybe we could help you...

Answer (score 0):

Check your routes and be sure that you passing params in apropriate way.

You can also use reload param set on true:

```
$state.go('state.name', {}, {reload: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we figured it out the problem why ui.router navigation is looping through in my application, ui-router is working fine when we use the state names and reload: true.

```
$state.go('state.name', {}, {reload: true});
```

This worked fine.

The actual problem we used Authentication token check on each page load when Rest api call, which is causing to loop through the routing elements. We used different mechanism to handle authentication of the user, this issue got fixed.